# How do I create an array containing indexes matching a criteria?

Tags: c#, arrays

given:

```
var args = new string[] { "-one",  "two",  "three",  "-four" };
```

what would magic function need to look like in order to make the following pass?

```
var result = MagicFunction(args);
Assert.AreEqual(0, result[0]);
Assert.AreEqual(3, result[1]);
Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Length);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] MagicFunction(string[] args)
{
    return args.Select((s, i) => new { Value = s, Index = i }) // Associate an index to each item
               .Where(o => o.Value.StartsWith("-"))            // Filter the values
               .Select(o => o.Index)                           // Select the index
               .ToArray();                                     // Convert to array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like prototype can do it for you:
http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/find

Comment: Oh, maybe not: it looked like JS but tags say C#